# GreenDAO: ToMany relation causes SQLite queries to be executed on UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-sqlite, greendao

When ToMany relation is defined on Entity, the generated code looks like this (ProductEntity has ToMany relation to MediaEntity):

```
/**
 * To-many relationship, resolved on first access (and after reset).
 * Changes to to-many relations are not persisted, make changes to the target entity.
 */
@Generated(hash = 580223476)
public List<MediaEntity> getMedia() {
    if (media == null) {
        final DaoSession daoSession = this.daoSession;
        if (daoSession == null) {
            throw new DaoException("Entity is detached from DAO context");
        }
        MediaEntityDao targetDao = daoSession.getMediaEntityDao();
        List<MediaEntity> mediaNew = targetDao._queryProductEntity_Media(productId);
        synchronized (this) {
            if(media == null) {
                media = mediaNew;
            }
        }
    }
    return media;
}
```

Now, even if we obtain instance of ProductEntity on background thread (e.g. using a custom Loader), its getMedia() method will be called on UI thread, which will cause the SQLite query caused by the first call to getMedia() to be executed on UI thread.

Is there a way to prevent this lazy loading of sub-objects and instruct GreenDao to resolve all dependencies and populate all fields upon parent entity creation/initialization?

Link to the corresponding support ticket on GreenDAO's github page: https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/issues/416

P.S. We could manually add calls to getMedia() after ProductEntity obtained from DaoSession, but this is not a valid solution: too error prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you wrote, one avoid lazy getters from talking to the database by preloading it in a background thread using the getter. There is no better way.

Sometimes it's even fine just to call the unitialized getter in the UI thread. It depends on your situation.